# How to filter out rows from a pivot table built from a cube, based on the value of a measure

Tags: filter, olap, cube, excel-2013, analyzer

I have a Pivot table built from a SSAS cube.
I visualize 1 measure and aggregate it by dimension 1 on rows.
Let's say i get 20 rows, each with its own value.
I want to see only those rows with the TOP 5 values.
How can I do this with Excel 2013 ?
How can I do this with Strategy Companion's "Analyzer" ?

In Analyzer for instance there is the possibility of highlighting the TOP N values but all the other ones are still shown. I do want to remove from visualization those rows that are not in the TOP 5.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibile to filter out rows in both programs in a similar way.
Select the context menu associated with the DIMENSION on the rows. You find something like "Show only the top" or "Advanced Filter..." in Analyzer and "Value Filters"/"Top 10..." in Excel.
From there you can set up your filter that does exactly what i was looking for, removing unwanted rows, not only highliting desider rows.